# zsh ignores the shebang in macOS Monterey

Tags: terminal, bash, zsh

#### Problem

In macOS Monterey, a script with a shebang (e.g. `#!/bin/sh`) is not executed by the indicated interpreter via zsh. For example, the following script will yields the below outcome:

---

#### Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $SHELL
```

---

#### Output

```
% chmod u+x my_script
% my_script
/bin/zsh
```

---

I want my scripts to run with bash. I would prefer that the shebang be respected than entirely change my shell. How can I ensure this happens?

##### Related questions that don't answer mine:

1. *The shebang doesn't work if you're sourcing the script with '.'*: I'm not
2. *Run the script like: `bash my_script`*: I want it to respect the shebang, not change my behaviour so I need to check each script before running it with the right shell.
3. *Change your shell to bash*: I wish to keep the standard macOS shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script is being run with bash. $SHELL is set once to the path to your login shell when it starts, **not** a dynamically changing value for the shell currently executing the command that prints $SHELL.

Answer (score 1):

One big difference is that bash by default sets the variable `SHELL`, but `zsh` doesn't. Therefore in some implementations, the system configuration (for instance via `/etc/zshenv`) set `SHELL` as environment variable to the zsh binary; AFIK, Apple is doing this in MacOS.

bash **would** set `SHELL` to the path of its binary, but it does this **only** if there is no environment variable of this name. You can verify this (while in zsh) with

```
SHELL=foo bash -c 'printenv SHELL'


(unset SHELL; bash -c 'echo $SHELL')
```

The first line will print *foo*, while the second one will print something like */bin/bash*.

Hence, if you want bash to get `SHELL` to be set, you have to unset it in your zsh before running your bash script. However, since the cases where this variable is actually **needed** are rare, I don't think this is worth the effort.